# On hover animate bottom border left to right

Tags: css

When you hover the bottom border should animate. The code is working in the first fiddle but not when I try to replicate it in the second fiddle.

```
#name:hover > .slider {
width: 100%;
}

.project-list .title a:hover > .slider {
width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/4/

https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/9/

Comment: `border` is not an element you can animate that way; it is either there or it's not, you can't make it grow while keeping the owning element a static width. The first JSFiddle is using a separate div and changing the width from 0% to 100% of the container's width.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

find **[working fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/14/)**

give position relative to a tag.

```
<a href="#modal7" class="nombore">
     <span>/07</span>
     <span class="slider"></span>  
 </a>

.nombore{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because this should be possible without an additional slider span.

Comment: Dear Poitroae, of course it is possible without additional span and slider element. For you I made a edited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/21/. I did it because in his question span and slider div was already there. So, I thought, he may be wanted like this.